# facebook oAuth is not redirecting back to application

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsp, oauth-2.0

I am trying to call facebook oauth login. Once pop up is appeared with facebook login page, It is not redirecting to same application again.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/mp/struts/js/base/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/mp/maincommon/static/js/all.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function onFaceBookAuth(user){
          var id = user['id'];
          var firstName = user['first_name'];
          var lastName = user['last_name'];
          var email = user['email'];

          var params = "applicantId="+id+"&firstName="+firstName+"&lastName="+lastName;
          var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } 
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    if(response.indexOf("new") != -1){
                        $('#applicantId').val(id);
                        $('#fbfirstName').val(firstName);
                        $('#fblastName').val(lastName);
                        $('#fbemail').val(email);
                        $('#applicantRegisterForm').submit();
                    }
                    else{
                        window.location = 'applicantHome.jsp?applicantId='+id;
                    }
                }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "login?mode=2", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(params);
    }

    function fbAsyncInit(){
       FB.init({appId: '307292312637177', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            var stringArr=JSON.stringify(response);
              if (response.status == 'connected') {
                  fbLoginStatus = true;
                  showLogoutText();
              } 
              else if (response.status == 'not_authorized') {
                  fbLoginStatus = false;
              } 
              else {
                // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
                  fbLoginStatus = false;
              }
             });
       FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
           FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    if(user.id!=undefined){
                    onFaceBookAuth(user);
                    }
                }
              });
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        });

        FB.api('/me', function(user) {
            if (user) {
                if(user.id!=undefined){
                onFaceBookAuth(user);
                }
            }
          });
    };

   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="facebookLogin" class="fb-login-button" onclick="fbAsyncInit()" data-scope="email">
                            Login with Facebook</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pop up is coming to enter facebook credentials. But, after that it is not redirecting back to same application.

Is this issue related  "appId" ? because i have given random number and i am not aware what to give for "appId". How to get appId for my application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the AppId is important. The AppId for your application is available from the Facebook developers page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

You need to register an application before you can interact with the Facebook API, and in order for oAuth to redirect correctly, you will need to supply it with the path to your site, which you set in the details form available at the url above.

There's more info on developing for Facebook at the root url: https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: i am tesing locally. currently it is not live. so, localhost url registration will work?

Comment: No. To test oAuth integration you will need to work with a publicly accessible url.

Comment: @JcFx, that is not true. All the relevant parts of the Auth flow happen inside your browser, and your browser knows which machine localhost is. Authentication using an app currently running only on localhost works perfectly fine, I do it all the time while developing locally.

Comment: @CBroe - but I thought Auth would only post back to the address you've entered in the app configuration? When I last tested this, it wouldn't post back to localhost. Happy to stand corrected if I'm wrong.

Comment: It does not “post” back, the user’s browser is simply redirected between facebook.com and your application. And since it’s the browser’s responsibility to “follow” redirects by issuing another (GET-)request, there is no problem … because, as said before, your browser/machine knows who localhost is. As long as no “pings” are involved, where Facebook actually tries to push data to your domain by itself, or instances where Facebook has to read data from your domain (Open Graph objects f.e.), working on localhost while developing works fine.

Comment: @CBroe - That's useful to learn. Just to clarify: where it says on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/summary 'URL for your website. For security reasons we (Facebook) will only redirect to this URL' - would you enter a localhost value there, or just leave that blank, or is that not relevant to the redirect carried out during oAuth login?

Comment: Putting `http://localhost/` into “Website with Facebook login” is usually enough. “App domains” does not have to be specified, if one wants to use only that address (or path under it) for login. But putting `localhost` in there as well does not hurt either.

Comment: @CBroe - thanks for the explanation. I'll leave my comment above as-is, as I think others can learn from this discussion.